# How can I change a Mac Address?

Tags: c#, mac-address

I haven't been able to find anything for this that works.
The code that I have tried using was this
Any ideas help

````
public static bool SetMAC(string nicid, string newmac)
        {
            bool ret = false;
            using (RegistryKey bkey = GetBaseKey())
            using (RegistryKey key = bkey.OpenSubKey(baseReg + nicid))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue("NetworkAddress", newmac, RegistryValueKind.String);

                    ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                        new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Index = " + nicid));

                    foreach (ManagementObject o in mos.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
                    {
                        o.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                        o.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
                        ret = true;
                    }
                }
            }```
I can't find where it is from but it didn't work.
````

Comment: Can you change the MAC address on the NIC in question normally through the OS?

Comment: Normally you would go to adapter options, ethernet, properties, and then you can change it there, is that what you mean?

Comment: Normally it's on the actual device itself, under "Advanced" and then "Network address".

Comment: You can not change it under eithernet in settings

Comment: In that case, I suspect you won't be able to change it through the registry either. I'm not 100% sure on this, but my guess is that the device driver doesn't support it.

Comment: Apparently you can change it thought the registry (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FopZ5Nx4rnM&t=2s)

Comment: Well, have you had success following this video and performing the steps manually?

Comment: Yes. I followed it and it worked

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Nope, not really. The best I can say is to check if the change is being made to the registry or not by the code.